# Using excel search function while there are multiple keywords

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a formula to return the position of the next keyword if there are multiple keywords? For example if I have "Gross Return Gross Return" in cell A1, is there a formula to get the position of the second Gross in excel?
For example if I use `=search("Gross",A1)`, the result would be **1**. But I want the result to be **14**.

Comment: what do you mean by position? can you give a proper example? with the expected result

Comment: For example if I use =search("Gross",A1), the result would be 1. But I want the result to be 14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the following formula:

```
=FIND("gross",A1,FIND("gross",A1)+2)
```

hope it works for you.

Comment: This is the actual problem: I have this text in A1. "The Gross Return of the S&P index over the past year has been 5%. The ISIN for this Gross Return is CH354892. The ISIN for Net Return is CH875621." I want to write a general function that would return the ISIN for Gross Return, which is CH354892. I was thinking of searching for the words "Gross Return" and "ISIN" and if the difference of the positions between them is < 35, I would grab the text starting 5 positions after Gross Return and ending at 8 positions after the start. Is there a way to do it? Thank you.

Comment: i think this is another question, please accept the answer to this question and put the new question as a new one. you can't ask another question in a comment. thanks